# passing data between component controller to main controller

Tags: angularjs, components

In my angular application I have only one component.
I want to call a `mainMethod` of main controller from component controller.

### main controller

```js
app.controller("mainController",function($scope)
{
   $scope.mainMethod = function()
   {
     console.log("its working");
   }
})
```

### main view

```xml
<card call-method="mainMethod()"><card>
```

### component controller

```js
app.component("card",{
   bindings:{
      callMethod:'&'
   },
   controller:compController,
   template:"<button on-click="$ctrl.triggerMethod()">call<button>"
})

function compController()
{
   function triggerMethod()
   {
      callMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: please ignore the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind `triggerMethod` to your component's `$ctrl`, and should call `$ctrl.callMethod()` as well:

```
function compController() {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.triggerMethod = function triggerMethod() {
    $ctrl.callMethod();
  };
}
```

Also you must update your template and use `ng-click` instead of `on-click`